# JHipster: Angular/TypeScript: console.log causes compile error

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

Silly question, but...

Playing around with JHipster 6.6.0, generated a simple monolithic application, started the application with `./gradlew` and `npm start`. Everything seems to work great.  Then I added a single line in the `src\main\webapp\app\home\home.component.ts` file `ngOnInit()` method:

```
console.log('Hello, world!');
```

And I get the following compile error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts
Module Error (from ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js):

..\src\main\webapp\app\home\home.component.ts
  22:5  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

Can't compile at all.  Only way to get around it is to remove the line altogether, then everything starts working again.

Any ideas why?  Perhaps there's a config setting I should change?  [I tried adding `no-console: false` rule to `tslint.json`, but that didn't make any difference.]  Is there a preferred way to add angular/typescript debug statements in JHipster?  What am I missing?

Thanks!

[*FYI*: Development environment is: Windows 10 Pro; IntelliJ 2019.3.2; OpenJDK 13; Node 12.14.1; Gradle 6.0.1; Chrome v79.0.3945.130]

**P.S.**: I notice the Chrome console is quite busy when running the application, so clearly there must be a way to get messages into the console, but the usual `console.log()` statement causes a compiler fail!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, jeez-louise!

Right after I posted my question, I noticed a `console.log()` statement in the `src\main\webapp\app\app.main.ts` file, preceded by a curious comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
```

I copied/pasted the comment from the `src\main\webapp\app\app.main.ts` file to the line just before my `console.log('Hello, World!')` statement, and... hey presto!

Now everything works!

A little esoteric...

Does anyone know: Is this the right way to add `console.log()` statements in JHipster?  Is there a better way?  Should I be avoiding `console.log()` statements altogether?  All feedback welcome!

Thanks, again!

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console you can disable this rule globally in `.eslintrc.json` alternatively you can create a log service and ignore this rule only in this service or use an existing one like ngx-logger